# Select drop-down and styling it's options

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my select box and the options drop down to be styled as shown in the image below. Please help me with the same. If only CSS can do that it would be great, else a javascript solution. Thanks in advance.

[image: Current select drop-down]

[image: New Requirement]

I am very new to Javascript and the front-end technologies. Currently, the below code is being used for the select box and getting it's options.

```
                        <div class="selectWrapper">
                                <label for="ext-comp-1001" class="inputLabel"><span class="required">*</span><fmt:message key="registration.country"/></label> 
                                <div class="x-form-element" id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1001">
                                    <input id="brand" name="spEntityID" type="hidden" value="<%=spEntityID%>" />
                                    <select autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1001" name="country" value="" class=" x-form-select-one x-form-field select_one select_one" onchange="changeStateList()"></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

In the above code some Javascript code brings all the countries and the Javascript code for it is all written in hexadecimal(UTF-8). Can I achieve this without touching the existing Javascript code which is difficult to decrypt and implement all the functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your task, you'll need some `JavaScript` along with a touch of `CSS`.

I prepared a demo for you so you can build on it even though it does include all the functionalities you want (I mean you'll probably not going to add that much as I had it all done for you).

So, how we'll we proceed :

- Firstly, we'll prepare our `HTML` (especially the `select` element) as usual and we'll add another element that will host the new or the `custom select` which has :

  - an element to show the selected `option`'s text.
  - an element that represents an arrow on the right (as that one which appears in the image included in the question).
  - an element to wrap the `option`s (`JavaScript` will populate that element along with changing the selected element text accordingly).
- populate the custom `select` with based on the "real" `select` options.
- change the `custom select` text with the selected `option` with `JavaScript`.

The next example illustrates what's being said, also it has some helpful comments :

```js
/** select the elements that are going to build the main functionalities of this task **/
const select = document.getElementById("select-box"),
  realOptions = select.options,
  customSelect = document.getElementById("custom-select"),
  selectedText = customSelect.querySelector(".selected-option-text"),
  optionsContainer = customSelect.querySelector(".options-container");
let idx = 0; /** this will help us get the correct index of the option when assigning the click event listener to the newly added custom options **/

/** add click listener to the custom "select" to open the custom options container **/
customSelect.addEventListener("click", () =>
  optionsContainer.classList.add("visible")
);


/** looping through the "option" elements of the real "select" **/
[...realOptions].forEach(el => {
  let currIdx = idx++; /** that will help us change the selected "option" on the real "select" eleement **/
  /** if the current real "option" is not disabled we add a custom one (in the custom "select") **/
  if (el.disabled === false) {
    /** create a new "p" element that will act as an "option" **/
    const customOption = document.createElement("p");
    customOption.classList.add("custom-option");
    /** the text of the "p" element is the same as the current (we're in a loop !) real "option" element **/
    customOption.textContent = el.textContent;
    /** add click listener to the "p" element that handles the click on a custom option which is the "p" element **/
    customOption.addEventListener("click", e => {
      /** the event doesn't propagate to the parent element to prevent the custom "select" from staying opened always (remember the click listener above for the parent (the custom "select")) **/
      e.stopPropagation();
      optionsContainer.classList.remove("visible");
      realOptions.selectedIndex = currIdx;
      selectedText.textContent = el.textContent;
    });
    /** add the "p" element which acts as an "option" to the custom "select" **/
    optionsContainer.append(customOption);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/** for demo purposes **/
select#select-box {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 50%; /** changes this per your requirements it's not that necessary **/
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #595859;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-select .arrows {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 6px;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.custom-select .arrows>.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.custom-select .selected-option-text {
  padding: 8px 6px;
  color: #595859;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.custom-select .options-container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 98%;
  max-height: 250px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #595859;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.custom-select .options-container.visible {
  display: block;
}

.custom-select .options-container>.custom-option {
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: default;
  transition: all .2s 0s ease;
}

.custom-select .options-container>.custom-option:hover {
  background-color: #ca2128;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" />
<select id="select-box">
  <option value="" disabled selected>select option</option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4</option>
  <option value="5">option 5</option>
  <option value="6">option 6</option>
  <option value="7">option 7</option>
  <option value="8">option 8</option>
  <option value="9">option 9</option>
  <option value="10">option 10</option>
</select>

<!-- nothing too fancy here just the "#custom-select" elemnt that will contain the custom select -->
<div id="custom-select" class="custom-select">
  <div class="selected-option-text">Please select an option</div>
  <div class="arrows">
    <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="options-container"></div>
</div>
```

You can customize that example to more fulfill your wanted end result.

I also didn't hide the real `select` so you can see it changes based on the option you select on the custom one.

I'm here for any clarification you want.

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: I have edited my post to add a bit more information. Can I achieve it in the existing code or without breaking the existing functionality.

Comment: Can you please help me with my above query.

Comment: @Ankit Sorry to be late. I'll check it out and update my answer ASAP (you'll be in touch).

Comment: Did you get time to go through it?

Comment: @Ankit what does my answer miss from your edit ? I mean what should I add in terms of functionalities because I read your edit and my answer still applicable to your issue.

Comment: In the code you provided, I am unable to understand how the options are getting filled in the select box. In the code that I have provided, ID# ext-comp-1001 is being used to populate the select box through some Javascript code (this is what I have figured out from the hex code). I my existing code, if I try to add even one extra div, it is somehow behaving abruptly, which I am unable to figure why. It would be great if you could explain how the select box is getting populated through your HTML and JS code. I am really new to this stuff. Sorry if my doubts seem too childish.

Comment: @Ankit In my example,I added manually some options to the `select` box and then used `JavaScript` to populate another `div.optionsContainer` with `p` elements that will act as a styled `select` box. The code that populate your `select` box doesn't interfere with the code I used to populate the custom and styled `select` box in my code. Just make sure, you have copied the markup for `div#custom-select` from my code above, the real select should have `select-box` as its `ID` (or you could change the `ID` in both `HTML` and `JavaScript` with your desired one) and put my code just before `</body>`

Comment: Will try it and get back to you in some time. Thanks for all the help till now.

Comment: @Ankit you're welcome at any time. Keep me in touch after you try what I had mentioned, good luck.

Comment: @Ankit another thing, my `JavaScript` code must appear after your code (that one populating the `select` box of yours).

Comment: Sorry for being late, was stuck with something else. This code does create a drop down, but does not work as expected. In my original <select> I have an onchange function that populates another dropdown with States, if states are valid for that country, else hides the states div. Also, when I click on one country in the dropdown, the country that populates in the original <select> box is different (as original drop-down has alphabetical sorting). To add on, this code gives 2 dropdowns(one is the original one and second is this one), how to keep only one. Hope I had enough reputation to chat.

Comment: Also, I want an options container with arrows at center without a scrollbar at the side and on clicking the top arrow content moves up and vice versa for down arrow. Also, need to limit the number of countries being displayed between the up and down arrows, which should be 12.

Comment: @Ankit Sorry but all that details aren't included in the question from the beginning. Anyway, could you make a CodePen example with the full code ?

Comment: @Ankit I'll take a look a bit later when I get back home.

Comment: @Ankit it works as intended ! See this [pen](https://codepen.io/Thabet_Sakhraoui/pen/GVqXdv).

Comment: The code does work in codepen, but somehow stops working in actual code. There is something that is stopping it which I will have to figure out. Can you help with the scroller part which looks like the image in actual post and has restriction of 12 countries between the two arrows.

Comment: @Ankit Am sorry to say it but the comments aren't meant to have such huge conversation. Also, to be clear I answered your question the way it is, meaning your environment is likely to be different from mine or SO's snippets.

Comment: Sorry for extended conversation, actually I am unable to chat with you due to lack of reputation. One last thing, can you help with the dropdown design as in the original post with two arrows in the center of the content.

Comment: it is possible but that may interfer with your `JavaScript` code as to allow the two arrows to scroll the dropdown we'll have to add more `JavaScript` code.

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks for all the time you devoted and help you gave.